# Different styles in one recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with a custom adapter and i am displaying news in recycler view. its working perfectly but its showing like given screen shots.
I need code example step by step. how can i acheive that.
My code of custom xml for recycler view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="#30000000">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_news"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_news_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

screen shot now displaying like this
[image]

but i want to display it like this
[image]

Comment: So there'll be one item then 2 items in same row and then 1 single item again? And this will keep repeating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the orientation of your linear layout horizontal instead of vertical on your linear layout above.`android:orientation="horizontal"`, specify the width in `dp` rather than match_parent for the image view and text view

`

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="#30000000">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_news"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="160dp" /> 

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_news_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_ content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: please check the screen shots. i want to display multiple design in one recycler view.